# How can different values be used as the same parameter one after another?

Tags: bash

I run a command in the terminal that outputs the below..

```
abc -> 1
bcd -> g
cde -> 2
def -> 3
efg -> 4
```

That you see on the left of `->` represents first parameter of another function and that you see on the right of `->` represents the second parameter of the same function.

What you see on the left is essentially paired with what is on the right, and I want to utilise this information in the other function.

- I had the idea of outputting what's on the left into one file and
  outputting what's on the right into another file
- Then creating a function that reads both files and pulls out the
  information one by one and uses it in the other function until all
  information has been used `i.e. after efg -> 4` has been
  used in the other function then it would stop.

My questions are:

1. How can different values be used as the same parameter one after another?
2. How can you pair two pieces of information from two separate files? So that the first of the pair is run as one parameter and the second of the pair is run as the other parameter.
3. Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell scripts are great for processing text and running commands. There's no need for temporary files. A simple loop can do it:

```
some_command | while read -r param1 _ param2; do
    use_values "$param1" "$param2"
done
```

Here `some_command` is a placeholder for the command that prints the output above and `use_values` is a placeholder for the "other function" that uses the two values.

I used `_` as a variable name for the `->` bit, which is ignored. `_` is a common idiom to indicate a variable that isn't used.